# SOAP WebService not giving response when passing argument

Tags: objective-c, xcode

```
This is SOAP WebService method:

<PostXMLStr xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <cust>string</cust>
      <tran>string</tran>
      <ret>string</ret>
      <ppay>string</ppay>
      <recp>string</recp>
      <sCode>string</sCode>
      <companyShortName>string</companyShortName>
      <companyCode>string</companyCode>

This is what i calling SOAP:
<PostXMLStr xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
    "      <cust><NEWCUSTOMERS><NEWCUSTOMER></NEWCUSTOMER></NEWCUSTOMERS></cust>\n"
    "      <tran><TRANS><TRAN></TRAN></TRANS></tran>\n"
    "       <ret><RETURNS><RETURN></RETURN></RETURNS></ret>\n"
    "       <ppay><PREPAYMENTS></PREPAYMENTS></ppay>\n"
    "       <recp><RECEIPTS><RECEIPT></RECEIPT></RECEIPTS></recp>\n"
    "       <sCode>BB</sCode>\n"
    "   <companyShortName>SAMINC</companyShortName>\n"
    "   <companyCode>01</companyCode>\n"
```

I have some problem when passing argument to SOAP WebService.I could not find it out.When i call another SOAP WebService which has not argument giving me response.I am assuming something problem with passing argument.any help will be appreciated.thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you to debug the web-service first. Here is an extension for Chrome to interact with any web-services: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en I'm 100% sure it is not a problem with Objective-C or Xcode, as you didn't provided any code.

Comment: i do not understand what are u saying?

Comment: He says that maybe your webservice doesn't respond your request, To test that, there are many tools, but you can use chrome extension as @Vova said.

Comment: thanks for explain it.

Comment: @user2134883 Did you control it ?

Comment: @user2134883 i have written request class for your reference, implement it and let me know the insights. good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written soap_parser Class to get read of making SOAP Message, its pretty straight forward to implement, just follow the steps and your through the problem.

Step 1: Create a .h file `soap_parser.h` with following code and make appropiate domain changes

```
#error Set Your Request Domain & Webservice name

#define DOMAIN_URL      @"http://yourDomain.com/WebService/"
#define SERVICE_URL     DOMAIN_URL@"/iphoneservice.asmx"
#define TEMP_URL        @"http://tempuri.org"

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol soap_parser_delegate <NSObject>

@optional
-(void)receivedResponseWithStatusCode:(NSInteger)statusCode;
-(void)requestFailedWithError:(NSError *)err;
@required
-(void)dataReceivingCompleted:(NSMutableData *)data;

@end

@interface soap_parser : NSObject
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *soap_request;
    NSURLResponse *soap_response;
    NSMutableData *soap_responseData;

    NSString *currentAction;

    id <soap_parser_delegate>delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData *soap_responseData;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *currentAction;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id <soap_parser_delegate>delegate;

#pragma mark - Initialize Parsing
-(void)startParsingWithAction:(NSString *)action andWithParams:(NSDictionary *)params;

#pragma mark - Create SOAP message
-(NSString *)createSoapMesssageFrom:(NSDictionary *)requestParam;

@end
```

Step 2: Create a .m file `soap_parser.m` with following code

```
#import "soap_parser.h"

@implementation soap_parser

@synthesize soap_responseData, currentAction, delegate;

#pragma mark - Initialize Parsing
-(void)startParsingWithAction:(NSString *)action andWithParams:(NSDictionary *)params
{
    self.currentAction = action;

    NSString *reqSOAPmsg = [self createSoapMesssageFrom:params];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:SERVICE_URL];

    soap_request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [reqSOAPmsg length]];

    [soap_request addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [soap_request addValue: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",TEMP_URL,self.currentAction] forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [soap_request addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [soap_request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [soap_request setHTTPBody: [reqSOAPmsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLConnection *cn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:soap_request delegate:self];
    [cn start];
}

#pragma mark - Create SOAP message
-(NSString *)createSoapMesssageFrom:(NSDictionary *)requestParam
{
    NSMutableString *soapMessage = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    [soapMessage appendFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
     "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
     "<soap:Body>\n"
     "<%@ xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n",self.currentAction];

    for(NSString *key in requestParam)
    {
        [soapMessage appendFormat:@"<%@>%@</%@>\n",key,[requestParam valueForKey:key],key];
    }
    [soapMessage appendFormat:@"</%@>\n"
     "</soap:Body>\n"
     "</soap:Envelope>",self.currentAction];

    NSLog(@"%@",soapMessage);
    return soapMessage;
}

#pragma mark - NSURLConnection Delegate
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;

    if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(receivedResponseWithStatusCode:)])
    {
        [delegate performSelector:@selector(receivedResponseWithStatusCode:) withObject:httpResponse];
    }
    self.soap_responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [self.soap_responseData appendData:data];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(requestFailedWithError:)])
    {
        [delegate performSelector:@selector(requestFailedWithError:) withObject:error];
    }

    connection = nil;
    self.soap_responseData = nil;
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(dataReceivingCompleted:)])
    {
        [delegate performSelector:@selector(dataReceivingCompleted:) withObject:self.soap_responseData];
    }
}

@end
```

Step 3: `#import "soap_parser.h"` and `<soap_parser_delegate>` in your `ViewController` .h file, where you want to make soap Call.

Step 4: Implement Following Delegate methods in your .m file

```
#pragma mark - SOAP parser Delegate
-(void)receivedResponseWithStatusCode:(NSInteger)statusCode
{
    NSLog(@"Status Code : %d",statusCode);
}

-(void)requestFailedWithError:(NSError *)err
{
    NSLog(@"Failed : %@",[err description]);
}

-(void)dataReceivingCompleted:(NSMutableData *)data
{
    NSLog(@"Response Data Length : %d",data.length);
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[data mutableBytes] length:[data length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",responseString);
    #warning Do something with your Response Data
}
```

Step 5: Create A Dictionary with Data to send in SOAP Request to Make a call to your SOAP_WEBSERVICE, and rest it will take care.

```
NSDictionary *dictParams = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"CUST ID", @"cust",
                            @"Transaction ID",@"tran",
                            @"Ret Value",@"ret",
                            @"PPAY Value",@"ppay",
                            @"RECP Value",@"recp",
                            @"SCODE Value",@"sCode",
                            @"MY COMPANY LTD.",@"companyShortName",
                            @"COMPANY_007",@"companyCode", nil];

// Create Object of SOAP_Parser
soap_parser *objSOAP = [[soap_parser alloc] init];
// Set Delegate to self
[objSOAP setDelegate:self];
// Send Request with param Dictionary
[objSOAP startParsingWithAction:@"UserLogin" andWithParams:dictParams];
```

Comment: yes @user2134883 its correct, put that `/AMSP/AMSPWS.asmx` in `SERVICE_URL` and `http://192.168.1.56` in `DOMAIN_URL`

Comment: I am getting response length 0.

Comment: have you set parameters properly? or may be problem with your serverside script, check it, and is it `GET` request or `POST`? because i am using `POST` request in this example, if it differs then change it in `-(void)startParsingWithAction:(NSString *)action andWithParams:(NSDictionary *)params` method of `soap_parser.m` file

Comment: when i run the code the command line output is<companyShortName>SAMINC</companyShortName>
<companyCode>01</companyCode>
<tran><TRANS><TRAN></TRAN></TRANS></tran>
<ppay><PREPAYMENTS></PREPAYMENTS></ppay>
<sCode>BB</sCode>
<ret><RETURNS><RETURN></RETURN></RETURNS></ret>
<cust><NEWCUSTOMERS><NEWCUSTOMER></NEWCUSTOMER></NEWCUSTOMERS></cust>
<recp><RECEIPTS><RECEIPT></RECEIPT></RECEIPTS></recp>
</PostXMLStr>

Comment: why parameters order changed in output?May it is reason for not getting response

Comment: NSDictionary *dictParams = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"<NEWCUSTOMERS><NEWCUSTOMER></NEWCUSTOMER></NEWCUSTOMERS>", @"cust",
                                @"<TRANS><TRAN></TRAN></TRANS>",@"tran",
                                @"<RETURNS><RETURN></RETURN></RETURNS>",@"ret",
                                @"<PREPAYMENTS></PREPAYMENTS>",@"ppay",
                                @"<RECEIPTS><RECEIPT></RECEIPT></RECEIPTS>",@"recp",

Comment: @"BB",@"sCode",
                                @"SAMINC",@"companyShortName",
                                @"01",@"companyCode", nil]; this is what i am passing parameters

Comment: i am amazed why are you sending <XML> tags in your request string, it should be only strings no XML, why are you doing this, thats why i have created dictionary for example

Comment: there are 8 arguments i used.first five argument i need to send that way.

Comment: thats now proper way, just send some plain dummy text instead of it and invoke the application

Comment: NSString *cust=@"<NEWCUSTOMERS><NEWCUSTOMER></NEWCUSTOMER></NEWCUSTOMERS>";
    NSString *trans=@"<TRANS><TRAN></TRAN></TRANS>";
    NSString *RETURNS=@"<RETURNS><RETURN></RETURN></RETURNS>";
    NSString *prepayment=@"<PREPAYMENTS></PREPAYMENTS>";
    NSString *receipt=@"<RECEIPTS><RECEIPT></RECEIPT></RECEIPTS>";

Comment: NSDictionary *dictParams = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"%@", @"cust",
                                @"%@",@"tran",
                                @"%@",@"ret",
                                @"%@",@"ppay",
                                @"%@",@"recp",
                                @"BB",@"sCode",
                                @"SAMINC",@"companyShortName",
                                @"01",@"companyCode", cust,trans,RETURNS,prepayment,receipt];

Comment: NSDictionary *dictParams = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:cust, @"cust",
                                trans,@"tran",
                                RETURNS,@"ret",
                                prepayment,@"ppay",
                                receipt,@"recp",
                                @"BB",@"sCode",
                                @"SAMINC",@"companyShortName",
                                @"01",@"companyCode", nil];   this is the correct way to put it.

Comment: it doesn't make any difference what ever is the order of parameter

Comment: still i am not getting response.check server side script and tell you.thanks for ur response

Comment: same WebService working for android.could not find out where is problem

Comment: did you check Request method "POST" or "GET"

Comment: when i not passing any argument i am getting response as <PostXMLStrResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><PostXMLStrResult>Value cannot be null.it is meaning that i connect to webservice

Comment: may be server not supported for Http.Android too had same problem using http.Is there any other way to call SOAP?

Comment: i dont think any other way for the same.

Comment: cust=string&tran=string&ret=string&ppay=string& this is what sample HTTPPost example i saw in server.is there problem with argment sending?

Comment: if you send parameter value concating with `&` then it means its `GET` request, which also refers as Query string, so change the request on your server and read data with `POST` request on server